# Is there a term for asteroseismology as applied to giant planets?

Tags: gas-giants, terminology, asteroseismology

Giant planets such as Jupiter have oscillations which enable analyses using the techniques of asteroseismology, for example [Gaulme et al. (2011)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3714) detected global modes on Jupiter via radial velocity measurements. Is there a specific term for this technique as applied to giant planets instead of stars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a specific term for this technique (asteroseismology) as applied to giant planets instead of stars?

No it seems there is not.

Instead, people just use normal literal constructions.

1. arXiv: ["Seismology of Giant Planets"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1740)"
2. arXiv: ["Jovian Seismology" and "giant planet seismology"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3714) or (*your planet here*) seismology in general
3. Space SE: ["Planetary normal-mode seismology"](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/28047/12102)

A good example of the Fourier imaging technique is SYMPA:

- [SYMPA, a dedicated instrument for Jovian seismology I. Principle and performance](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2007/42/aa7019-06.pdf)
- [SYMPA, a dedicated instrument for Jovian seismology
  II. Real performance and first results](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2008/41/aa09512-08.pdf)

JOVIAL is next-gen implementation, also from Earth:

- [JOVIAL; **J**ovian **O**scillations through radial **V**elocimetry **I**m**A**ging observations at several **L**ongitudes](http://www.ajax.ehu.es/Juno_amateur_workshop/talks/01_06_Jupiter_oscillations_Schmider).
- [Jupiter’s interior: from gravimetry to seismology](https://www-n.oca.eu/jovial2016/Kick-off_Avril2016/Monday/JOVIAL_Guillot.pdf)

**note:** after posting I realized that one of the linked papers is the same as in the OP"s question. I'll leave it here for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Although there is not much point looking for them on the surfaces of the giant planets, as those are too dynamic, unfortunately.

However, the rings of Saturn can give us some insight into internal oscillation modes, this area of research is then dubbed [Kronoseismology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kronoseismology).

According to my (very limited) view of the developments in this subfield of planetary science, results were coming in only slowly and with low accuracy.

But since Cassinis grand finale hit us, we have close up observations of moving density waves in the rings, together with high-precision orbital data, so it seems [research is picking up speed](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0019103518303397) in recent years.